Unity Player isnt removed from lobby when exiting with alt f4
When a player leaves with a button to leave the lobby he is removed from the lobby and new playes can join. but when a player leaves with alt f4 the lobby still thinks that the lobby is full. How can i fix this?
The server can see when a player disconnects and im trying to remove the player.
 public void StartHost()
    {
        NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectionApprovalCallback += NetworkManager_ConnectionApprovalCallback;
        NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback; ;
        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    }

    private void NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback(ulong clientId)
    {
        if (IsServer)
        {
            // Log the disconnection
            Debug.Log($"ONMUILTIPLAYERMANAGER Client {clientId} disconnected.");

            // Update the lobby by removing the player
            GameLobby.Instance?.DisconnectPlayer(clientId.ToString());

            // Optionally handle any cleanup like respawning or managing game state.
        }
    }

    private void NetworkManager_ConnectionApprovalCallback(NetworkManager.ConnectionApprovalRequest connectionApprovalRequest, NetworkManager.ConnectionApprovalResponse connectionApprovalResponse)
    {
        connectionApprovalResponse.Approved = true;
    }

i also tried updating the lobby slots but nothing works.
public async void DisconnectPlayer(string playerId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (joinedLobby != null)
            {
                // First, check if the player exists in the lobby
                var player = joinedLobby.Players.Find(p => p.Id == playerId);
                if (player != null)
                {
                    // Attempt to remove the player from the lobby
                    await LobbyService.Instance.RemovePlayerAsync(joinedLobby.Id, playerId);
                    Debug.Log($"Player {playerId} successfully removed from lobby.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log($"Player {playerId} not found in the lobby.");
                }

                // Force update the lobby slots after the player leaves
                await UpdateLobbySlots();

                // Optionally, refresh the lobby state
                joinedLobby = await LobbyService.Instance.GetLobbyAsync(joinedLobby.Id);
                Debug.Log("Lobby slots updated after player disconnection.");
            }
        }
        catch (LobbyServiceException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to remove player {playerId}: {e.Message}");
        }
    }


    private async Task UpdateLobbySlots()
    {
        try
        {
            // Force update lobby data to reflect the correct available slots
            await LobbyService.Instance.UpdateLobbyAsync(joinedLobby.Id, new UpdateLobbyOptions
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>
                {
                    { "availableSlots", new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, (MultiplayerManager.MAX_PLAYER_AMOUNT - joinedLobby.Players.Count).ToString()) }
                }
            });

            Debug.Log("Lobby slots successfully updated.");
            Debug.Log(joinedLobby.Players.Count);
        }
        catch (LobbyServiceException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to update lobby slots: {e.Message}");
        }
    }


Is the lobby somehow synchronized as well? Note that OnClientDisconnectCallback is only called on the server and the disconnected client itself - not as you might think on all connected clients -> your server would have to ensure that this event is synchronized to other still connected players (if this is not fine by the lobby which I don't know)

You can use the OnApplicationQuit method to manage cleanup just before your application closes. This is particularly helpful for handling disconnections when a player leaves the game, whether they do so normally or by using shortcuts like Alt+F4.
